# How to make a function that takes a string and replace some letters with another symbols

Tags: arrays, swift, function, for-in-loop

For example, we can replace “a” or “A” with @ and get “с@t” instead of “cat”. Letters to replace: a - @; i - 1; s - $; o - 0; t - +

Using a for-in or forEach() methods.

I used this option but it's easy and not flexible.

```
func replaceOld(characters: String) -> String {
    let newChars = characters.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "@")
                             .replacingOccurrences(of: "i", with: "1")
                             .replacingOccurrences(of: "s", with: "$")
                             .replacingOccurrences(of: "o", with: "0")
                             .replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "+")
    return newChars

}
replaceOld(characters: "Swift is awesome")
```

> print Sw1f+ 1$ @we$0me

I created an array and I want to loop through and change the values.

```
func replaceOld(characters: String) -> String {
    var arrayOfChars = [("a", "@"), ("i", "1"), ("s", "$"), ("o", "0"), ("t", "+")]
    ....
}
```

But I still don't understand how to change the values ​​​​and pass it to the argument characters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let characterMapping: [Character: Character] = [
    "e": "3",
    "o": "0"
]
let newString = myString.map { character in
    return characterMapping[character] ?? character
}

// Hello World -> H3ll0 W0rld
```

You could bake all this into a function, or even parameterize the mapping. Another thing to keep in mind is going to be capitalization, diacritics, localization, etc.